# React Native Toolbar is not displaying

Tags: react-native

I am just React Native beginner.I have just created NavigatorDrawer with classes Home.js and Team.js.I have just added toolbar but it's not displaying. Can anyone look at my code and help me where I have done a mistake.

**Home.js**

```
const { navigate } = props.navigation;
return (
    <ToolbarAndroid
     title='Home'
     style={styles.toolbar}
     titleColor='white'
    />
    <View>
    <Text style={styles.abt}Home</Text>
    </View>
      );
```

**index.android.js:**

```
       render()
       {
       const { navigation } =this.props;
       return (
       <Home navigation={ navigation }/>      );
       }
       }
      const App =DrawerNavigator({
      Home:{screen:Home},
      Team :{ screen: Team},
      Wallpapers:{screen: Wallpapers},
      });
```